# Product moment correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

How to know if $pmcc>0$ or $pmcc<0$ if I am provided the two gradients of the regression lines? Since $pmcc=±√product~of~gradients$, how to deduce the sign of pmcc?

Comment: What are the "gradients of the regression line"?

Comment: If the regression lines are of the form $y=a+bx$ and $x=d+cy$ then $b$ and $c$ are the gradients and are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the slope $\hat{b}$ of the regression line, then you know the sign of $\hat{\rho}=r_{XY}$. Note that,
$$
r_{XY}= \frac{\sum(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sqrt{ \sum(X_i - \bar{X})^2 \sum(Y_i - \bar{Y}) }},
$$
and 
$$
\hat{b}= \frac{\sum(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})}{\sum(X_i - \bar{X})^2 },
$$
hence, $\sum(X_i - \bar{X})(Y_i - \bar{Y})$ determines the sign of the (estimated) slope and the (estimated) correlation coefficient.

Comment: But what if I am provided two regression lines, one y on x and second x on y. What will be the signs of pmcc if 1. Both slopes are positive? 2. Both slopes are negative? 3. Both have different signs? You have only talked about $S_{XY}$ but how can I determine that just from the slop of the line?

Comment: 1. positive. 2. negative. 3. Impossible

Comment: In third case is it impossible to determine just from gradients or is impossible for two regression lines to have different gradients?

Comment: Impossible as the sign determined by the $\widehat{cov(X,Y)}$ estimator, that remains the same whether you regress $Y$ on $X$ or vice versa.

Comment: Oh okay perfect. Thank you very muchZ